# problema ao chamar modal

Tags: php, html, modal

Estou começando a aprender sobre modal, então procurei alguns exemplos e encontrei um que me ajudava no que preciso, porém, esta com algum erro que não consigo
identificar.
O código é este:

```html
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-customer="<?php echo $id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Excluir</a>
```

Porém ao invés de abrir o modal.php ele abre o index.php.

Se eu fizer de uma dessas duas maneiras ele abre o modal, só que não pega o id.

```html
<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-customer="<?php echo $id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Excluir </a>
```

ou

```html
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-customer="<?php echo $id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Excluir </a>
```

**obs.:

- Onde encontrei esse exemplo muitos conseguiram rodar o código.
- A variavel $id pega um id selecionado do banco de dados (sem o modal esta funcionando perfeitamente).
- A função delete.php esta funcionando perfeitamente sem o modal.**

Comment: O que vc pretende? abrir o modal e ser redirecionado para delete.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>

Comment: Esse modal é para mostrar o que?

Comment: pretendo abrir o modal onde abre uma tela de confirmação de exclusão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a API [**.data()**](https://api.jquery.com/data/) do jQuery para recuperar o id

```
<a href="#myModal" ... data-customer="<?php echo $id; ?>"> ...

valorId = $(this).data('customer');
```

### Exemplo - código completo

**Biblioteca**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Script**

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
     valorId = $(this).data('customer');
     $(".modal-footer").html( '<a href="delete.php?id='+valorId+'" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light"> Excluir </a> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Cancelar</button>' );
     $('#myModal').modal('show');          
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-customer="<?php echo $id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Abrir Modal </a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Excluir id</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
             ............
             ............
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito bom !
Era isso mesmo que eu precisava
Dessa maneira esta pegando o id pelo jquery.
Obrigado.